# "Device is unreachable" Error message when trying to import media from iPhone to Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, iphone

While trying to import photos and video from your iPhone onto your PC, I kept getting an error message. I would go to This PC/AppleiPhone/DCIM and locate the media I wanted to import. Then I would attempt to copy and paste the media into a folder on the desktop. I got the error message "Device is unreachable."

Answer (score 10):

I was able to fix this problem by simply changing a setting on my iPhone. If you have the same problem, go to Settings/Photos and scroll down to "Transfer to Mac or PC." "Keep Originals" should be checked, not "Automatic." Simply changing this setting solved my problem.

(Thanks to Micatek for the solution Ref: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8351572)

Comment: this seems to _help_, but I eventually always get the same "device is unreachable" after copying a bunch of photos off, or even doing a file comparison action.

Comment: One possible suggestion: turn off cellular data, WiFi, and Bluetooth. It's possible notifications or iCloud syncing are somehow interrupting bulk file transfer over USB?

Comment: in the end I gave up, multiple Windows 10 machines had the same problem even with all the above tweaks. I plugged the iPhone into a Chromebook and it copied all the ~5600 photos and videos off perfectly the first time.

Comment: @JeffAtwood You are right it is so painful to transfer the photos and videos from iphone to windows 10 computer.
Today I finished my transfer in two steps
1. To transfer photos in settings I checked "Automatic"  as I want my photos to be in jpeg (Note: If I select "Keep Originals" photos will be heic format)
2. To transfer videos in settings I checked "Keep Originals" this make videos transfer successful otherwise I get "Device not reachable" error after sometime.
Hope this helps someone in future. I think Mac users will not have these problems